# AWS-CLI installed but not working (Command 'aws' not found) Ubuntu 18.04. How to solve it?

Tags: command-line, 18.04, aws

Following these steps to install **AWS-CLI** in a brand new Ubuntu **18.04**:

1. `sudo apt update`
2. `sudo apt upgrade`
3. `sudo apt install python3-pip`
4. `sudo apt install npm` (I will working with NodeJS)
5. `pip3 install awscli --upgrade --user`

After the step 5 I should be able to see the `aws-cli` version. But this is what I get:

1. `aws --version`

   Command 'aws' not found, but can be installed with:

   `sudo apt install awscli` (I did nothing)

But If I check in `ll ~/.local/bin`
This is what I have:

```
drwxrwxr-x 2 ubuntu ubuntu 4096 Jun 22 15:46 __pycache__/
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu  815 Jun 22 15:46 aws*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1432 Jun 22 15:46 aws.cmd*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu  204 Jun 22 15:46 aws_bash_completer*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1136 Jun 22 15:46 aws_completer*
-rwxrwxr-x 1 ubuntu ubuntu 1807 Jun 22 15:46 aws_zsh_completer.sh*
```

2. If I run `python3 -m awscli --version` this is what I get:

   aws-cli/1.18.84 Python/3.6.9 Linux/4.15.0-1065-aws botocore/1.17.7

So it seems that `aws-cli` is installed and already in `~/.local/bin` but not respond to the `aws configure` command.

What am I missing?

UPDATE

---

This is what  have in the `$PATH`

```
echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin
```

Comment: Is `.local/bin` in your `$PATH`?

Comment: No. I have `/usr/local/bin`

Comment: @zwitterion I have an explanation below. You don't need to add it to your path, it will add automatically if you log out and log back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~/.local/bin` is not currently in your `$PATH` because it did not exist when you opened your shell.

Log out and log back in to fix this problem.

---

To explain, if you take a look at your `~/.profile` file, you will see the following lines:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

If you look closely, you will see that `$HOME/.local/bin` will be added to your path if and only if it exists.

So, the first time you install something locally with pip, you will need to log out and log back in.

---

Alternatively, you can also source your `~/.profile` file if you don't want to log out:

```
source ~/.profile
```

or

```
. ~/.profile
```

Comment: Log out and log back in to fix this problem. - OK - worked!